# How to get the unique visitors of 1 month in a web application?

Tags: statistics

I would like to know how much unique visitors I have on some webapplication. In this webapplication are a lot of site collections and pages. So everything needs to be included. I would like also to know it for 1 month. What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: Are you wanting user account information (i.e. account name and last access date) or just the total of unique visitors for the month?

Comment: just the total number. No user account information needed.

Comment: Take a look at this post. You can get what you need from the web analytics reports.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: nice post, I see it is possible to get statistics from a whole web application. How to get this statistics report? I know only how to get the website and site collection statistics report.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings

Click "Site Web Analytics reports" under Site Actions

[image: Site Actions]

Click "Number of Daily Unique Visitors"

This will give you the daily break down and total for 30 days for the web application.

You can change the time range by clicking "Change Settings"

[image]

Comment: which scope are you talking about? I need unique visitors for a whole web application and all site collections/websites below it.

Comment: This report includes that. If you wanted it just for this site collection, you click the link below that one.